# $\frac{26!}{\sum_{k=1}^{26} \binom{26}{k}k!}$ trouble understanding how factorials are factored and how it's derives to Taylor series

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, factorial

I am trying to understand how a probability function is derived to Taylor series and how the factorials were factored to the final answer.

$$\frac{26!}{\sum_{k=1}^{26} \binom{26}{k}k!}\\
= \frac{26!}{ \sum_{k=1}^{26} \frac{26!}{k!(26-k)!}k!}\\
= \frac{26!}{\frac{26!}{25!}+\frac{26!}{24!}+\cdots +\frac{26!}{1!}}$$

I can understand the content of the above functions, however, i can't understand how it derives to:

$$= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{25!}+\frac{1}{24!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1!}+1}$$

Why are all the numerators (26!) of the denominators changed to 1 (examples: $\frac{26!}{25!}$ changed to $\frac{1}{25!}$)?

kindly advise. Regards

Comment: Two things happened in that step. You noticed the numerators of all the little fractions. But what happened to the numerator of the big fraction?

Comment: the numerator of the big fraction has being changed to 1 too. are you implying that 26! from the "big" fraction is used for factoring all the numerators of all the 26! from the little fractions?

Comment: It's just dividing the numerator and denominatir by $26!$

Comment: Well, what is the one special thing you learn from early on that you can do to fractions, which doesn't change their value but changes what they look like? Does it look like maybe that's what has happened here?

Comment: $\dfrac{a}{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{a}{d}} = \dfrac{a}{a\left(\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}} $

Comment: It is just *distribution* and cancelation of common factors. $$\dfrac{26!}{(26!\,a+\cdots+26!\,z)}=\require{cancel}\dfrac{\cancel{26!}}{\cancel{26!}}\dfrac{1}{(a+\cdots+z)}$$

Comment: @Henry, thank you for breaking up the functions, it clearly explains how the 1's were derived.